# How to fix permission denied publickey on Windows10 Git Bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, permissions, git, public-key

I'm unable to ssh into a machine that operates bots of my friend. He added my public ssh key, so i can join, but I get the permission denied privatkey error message.
*I removed the actual ip*

```
$ ssh -vT root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:BfcBpJfQqEgv4TGlGC6lfm+WuBuuei9OuovCVXfncM0
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:UIn33GRpXKKtWObWWC2u7h2K2OaevlNVeI6MsZZ0oTs
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:UIn33GRpXKKtWObWWC2u7h2K2OaevlNVeI6MsZZ0oTs
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/timm2/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey).
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUulQ.png) is how my file structure looks like. I added the ssh to my github. I followed this [guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to create the key.

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem on your friend's SSH server. It is not something you can fix.

Comment: We fixed it now. The solution was adding the keys to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and restarting the ssh server.